# Dynamically position a UITableView created from StoryBoard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have created a `UITableView` on a `StoryBoard` which doesn't fill the entire screen, it starts a little ways down. I am doing this because I want other content, such as label and buttons to be above it which I am creating programmatically.

[image]

When I run the app in the simulator for the regular iPhone and the iPhone 4 retina everything is positioned correctly.

[image]

However, when ran for the iPhone 5, the `UITableView` has a gap between the top of the buttons and labels and where it starts.

[image]

I tried to write code that checks for the iPhone 5 and then reposition the `UITableView` up higher, however, no matter what value I enter for the frame, the `UITableView` never moves.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if([iDevice screenResolutionHeight] == IPHONE_5)
    {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.mytableView.frame.size.width,self.mytableView.frame.size.height)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: the CGRectMake has the tableView's width as parameter for both height and width in your code. Typo?

Comment: It was, thanks! I updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a height constraint on your table view. You should create a constraint to the bottom of the superview, and another to the bottom of the upper blue view ( the one with All and Filter). If you give that blue view a height constraint, then you should be able to remove the height constraint to the table view.

Comment: Yes, there is a height constraint on there of 390. I'll need to read up more on the constraints to see if that works.

Comment: This is certainly the right approach. I am still messing around with it but marking this as answer!

These two videos helped me understand constraints and pins better: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3to5m3zuTEw  and   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhJbCAzAS2Q

Answer (score 0):

I was still having a lot of problems with this with `Auto Layout` and the `constraints`. I ended up just turning off `Auto Layout` for the `StoryBoard` and used the `Autosizing` capabilities which worked for me. It might not work for every app but it's just another option I wanted to share.

[image]